# dimesion percentage over over time by line chart in Tableau

Tags: plot, tableau-api

In a dimension item, I have 3 categories (say: A,B,C) and would like to plot the measure of A as percentage of total (A,B,C combined) over time. And I tried something very simple `SUM(IF [category] = "A" THEN [Some Amt] ELSE 0 END) / TOTAL(SUM([Some Amt]))`, but it always return 0. (I had put the time dimension in the column field) Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand after reading you OP, this will be the right syntax:

```
SUM(IF [category] = "A" THEN [Some Amt] ELSE 0 END) / SUM([Some Amt])
```

In addition, take in consideration that the number might be as integer so you will see 0 (Since it is a fraction) so you can format it to percentage. 
Right click your calculation inside the worksheet, (not on the measure on the left ) and choose format -> percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I am using in my data select only one customer name my calculation filed result 1.

SUM(IF [Customer Name] = "Aaron Hawkins" THEN [Sales] ELSE 0 END) / SUM([Sales])

[image]

percentage of total sale particular customer.

[image]